# Leer fichero .txt (Con tildes) en java

Tags: java, codificación

Estoy tratando de leer un fichero con extensión `.txt` para copiar las palabras a otro fichero.

El problema es que si el fichero original tiene tildes o caracteres especiales, el programa no funciona.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String palabra;
    Scanner input = null;
    PrintStream output = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("Quijote01.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        output = new PrintStream(new File("Copia.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(input.hasNext()){

        palabra = input.next();
        output.println(palabra);

    }
}
```

¿Cuál es el problema?
Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buenas, tienes que especificar el encoding del texto que tienes escrito en el archivo, por ejemplo:

```
fr = new FileReader (archivo, "UTF-8");

fr = new FileReader (archivo, "ISO-8859-1");

fr = new FileReader (archivo, "cp1252");
```